# Droppable is not firing in jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

HTML:

```
<ul id="tree">
    <li id="1">test1</li>
     <li id="2">test2</li>
     <li id="3">test3</li>
     <li id="4">test4</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#tree li").draggable().droppable({
  element: '#tree',
  tolerance: 'around',
  aroundTop: '25%',
  aroundBottom: '25%',
  aroundLeft: 0,
  aroundRight: 0,
  drop: function(event,ui) {
    id = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(id);
  }
});
```

But the drop event is not firing. I don't get alert. Unable be find the mistake.

Here is [Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shree/xxULt/1/) and [ui.overState fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shree/xxULt/3/)

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to exist and `around` value for [**tolerance**](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-tolerance) option, current valid values are `fit` `intersect` `pointer` `touch`, so if you just comment out your `tolerance` line, your fiddle works.

See [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xxULt/2/)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.Does `ui.overState` in jQuery UI 1.9.2 deprecated ? I have some working code in 1.8 but when I upgrade js i got a problem.If yes what is this alternative solutin.See my next Fiddle.Thanks again for help